# Problema con validación de datos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Validar los datos de un formulario y que se añadan en una tabla con javascript. si valido los datos no se añade la tabla y si añado la tabla no valida.

Tengo el código, pensé que al crear la función validarformulario podría almacenar la de añadir musica y que al introducir los datos se crearía la tabla.
Si no se añaden los datos, me aparece n mensaje de que los campos son obligatorios, pero l introducirlos, no se añade la fila, pero al quitar la función de validar se genera la tabla aunque no tenga datos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lista de canciones de Anime</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: black 3px 9px 10px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 3, 34), magenta);
        }

        h3 {
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: black 3px 9px 10px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 3, 34), magenta);
            font-style: oblique;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            color: rgb(44, 4, 4);
            text-shadow: rgb(129, 0, 141) 2px 2px 5px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-style: italic;
            height: 28px;
            width: 500px;
        }

        #mitabla {
            width: 40%;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 100px auto;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        th {
            border: 1px solid rgb(129, 0, 141);
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 3, 34), magenta);
            color: white;
            height: 55px;
            text-shadow: black 5px 5px 5px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid rgb(151, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid rgb(129, 0, 141);
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 74, 158), aqua);
            color: white;
            text-shadow: black 2px 2px 4px;
            height: 0px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        form {
            width: 680px;
            padding: 30px;
            background-image: url(105-1055085_music-wallpapers-for-phones.jpg);
            background-size: 750px 1300px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 100px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: lighter;
            text-shadow: black 5px 5px 105px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        legend {
            font-size: 35px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            margin: 1px;
            text-align: left;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: rgb(183, 0, 255) 2px 2px 5px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        #fielcont {
            margin: 5px;
            box-shadow: rgb(195, 0, 255) 5px 10px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        input#puesto {
            height: 25px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: rgb(129, 0, 141) 2px 2px 5px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        input#anime {
            height: 25px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: rgb(129, 0, 141) 2px 2px 5px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        input#cancion {
            height: 25px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: rgb(129, 0, 141) 2px 2px 5px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        .btn {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .btn1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            color: rgb(44, 4, 4);
            text-shadow: rgb(129, 0, 141) 2px 2px 5px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
```

He colocado todo el código. Función validarFormulario: en esta introduje la función addMusic, pensando que al darle al boton de añadir, en caso de que algún dato estuviera incompleto, me saldría el mensaje de que todos los campos son obligatorios. El problema es que, aunque me sale el mensaje, se sigue creando la tabla y no debería ser así.

```
</head>

<body>
    <h1><em>BEST ANIME MUSIC</em></h1>

    <table id="mitabla" contenteditable>
        <thead>
            <th>PUESTO</th>
            <th>ANIME</th>
            <th>CANCIÓN</th>
            <th> BORRAR</th>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validarFormulario(addMusic) {
            var anime = document.getElementById("anime").value
            var cancion = document.getElementById("cancion").value
            if (anime == "") {
                alert("El nombre del anime es obligatorio");
                document.getElementById("anime").focus();
            } else {
                if (cancion == "") {
                    alert("El nombre de la canción es obligatorio");
                    document.getElementById("cancion").focus();
                } else {
                    console.log(puesto + "" + anime + "" + cancion);
                    document.getElementById("anime").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("cancion").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("anime").focus();
                }
            }
        }
```

Si quito la función validar y en el onclick coloco la función addmusic no puedo validar los datos, y me gustaría que se pudiera validar para que se generé la tabla. He visto otras opciones con JQuery, necesitaría hacerlo con JavaScript y no tener y no tener que modificar tanto el código.

¿Es posible que con el mismo onclick pueda validar el formulario e introducir los datos a lavez?

```
function addMusic(validarFormulario) {

            var puesto = document.simple.puesto.value;
            var anime = document.simple.anime.value;
            var cancion = document.simple.cancion.value;

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            var td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            var td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            var td3 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            var td4 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

            td1.innerHTML = puesto;
            td2.innerHTML = anime;
            td3.innerHTML = cancion;
            td4.innerHTML = '<input type="image" src="IMAGENES/icons8-delete-64.png" onclick="delMusic(this);" class="btn btn-danger">'

            document.getElementById("mitabla").appendChild(tr);

        }

        function delMusic(Music) {
            var s = Music.parentNode.parentNode;
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);

        }

    </script>
```

A partir de aquí están los imputs que quiero añadir:

```
<div class="container">
        <h3>REGISTRA LA CANCION DE TU ANIME FAVORITO</h3>

        <form id="validarFormulario" name="simple">
            <br>
            <fieldset id="fielcont">
                <legend>Datos la lista</legend>
                <label id="lab1">PUESTO:</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Escribre el puesto" name="puesto" id="puesto" required><br>
                <label id="lab2">ANIME:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escribre el nombre del anime" name="anime" id="anime" required><br>
                <label id="lab3">CANCIÓN:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escribre el nombre de la canción" name="cancion" id="cancion" required><br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="add" value="Añadir" onclick="addMusic(validarFormulario);" class="btn1 btn-success">
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Un pequeño detalle... lo que encierra una función entre paréntesis son parámetros, no otras funciones, que luego se usan dentro de la función, como bien haces en `function delMusic(Music)`.  En cambio, en las otras dos funciones, que son `function validarFormulario(addMusic)` y `function addMusic(validarFormulario)`, no usas el parámetro que "teoricamente" les estas pasando.  Sabiendo esto intenta comprender mejor lo que estas haciendo a ver si te sale, y en caso contrario, corrige el código de la pregunta arreglando esos primeros errores básicos.

Comment: Para modificar tu pregunta puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta en color gris tantas veces como sea necesario.